# Unexpected parsing of SAS macro function

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to use `catx()` in `%sysfunc()`, test code like this:

```
%let newtext=%sysfunc(catx(%str(, ),%str(grade>80),test text));
%put &=newtext;

%let newtext=%sysfunc(catx(%str(, ),%str(grade<80),test text));
%put &=newtext;
```

However, SAS take `%str(grade>80)` as an expression and just resolve it as 1. The result of above code is

```
NEWTEXT=1, test text
NEWTEXT=0, test text
```

I want SAS just return the **RAW TEXT**, that is:

```
NEWTEXT=grade>80, test text
NEWTEXT=grade<80, test text
```

How to avoid this kind of unexpected parsing while using `%sysfunc()` or `%qsysfunc()`?

Comment: Use literal concatenation, as explained in answer to your second question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use literal concatenation in macro

```
%let newtext=grade>80,test text;
```

Use catx in DATA Step

```
newtext = catx(',', 'grade>80', 'test text');
```

Comment: Yes! I realize I don't need `%sysfunc(catx())` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use %SYSFUNC() with data step functions like CATX() that allow arguments to be either numbers or strings.  That causes %SYSFUNC() to have to make a guess about what type of value the text you are passing it represents so it can tell the data step function what type of arguments it is receiving.

To concatenate in macro code just expand the values next to each other.

```
%let newtext=grade>80,test text;
```

To handle the optional insertion of the delimiter that CATX() does add your own macro logic.

```
%macro catx(dlm,left,right);
   %if %length(&left) and %length(&right) %then &left.&dlm.&right ;
   %else &left.&right ;
%mend;
```

Comment: I think your saying is right. I have tried `cat()`, `catx()`, `cats()` and `catt()`, they all behaved the same. I have tried other functions and they didn't. Are `cat*()` the all functions that allow arguments to be either numbers or characters?